# Plotly js: latex not working

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly

I can't make latex working in plotly.

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [1, 4, 9, 16],
  name: '$\alpha_{1c} = 352 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [0.5, 2, 4.5, 8],
  name: '$\beta_{1c} = 25 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {title: '$\sqrt{(n_\text{c}(t|{T_\text{early}}))}$'},
  yaxis: {title: '$d, r \text{ (solar radius)}$'}
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Here is an example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gn1nnaup/

Example was taken from https://plot.ly/javascript/LaTeX/

It throws the following error: `plotly-latest.min.js:11 Error: <rect> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".`

Comment: For what it's worth now: I've had a very similar issue but it was resolved with the current version of Plotly.

Comment: @Christof: It seems that one needs to escape the backslashes with another backslash, at least on JSfiddle and SO it is required.

Answer (score 0):

You need two tiny changes to your fiddle.

1. `MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG` instead of `MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML`
2. In your code/import the `TeX` library has to come [before](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/dist/README.md) the `Plotly` library

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [1, 4, 9, 16],
  name: '$\\alpha_{1c} = 352 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}$',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [0.5, 2, 4.5, 8],
  name: '$\\beta_{1c} = 25 \\pm 11 \\text{ km s}^{-1}$',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {title: '$\\sqrt{(n_\\text{c}(t|{T_\\text{early}}))}$'},
  yaxis: {title: '$d, r \\text{ (solar radius)}$'}
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.